# Regex to match details/1234/something

Tags: javascript, regex, path

What would be the regex to match the following path (url):
Examples :

`/batches/123/details`
`/batches/234/something`
`/batches/3234/otherpath`
the string should start with "/batches" & should continue to have "/3213" i.e "/{number}"

Tried the /^(batches)/(\d+)+[/]?/.test('/batches/34/details') returns false

Comment: Your regex checks for `batches` at the beginning, but your paths start with a `/`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is your friend; it will tell you what the regex you've typed actually means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(\/batches\/)(\d+)
```

This matches everything that starts with "/batches/" and has some numbers after it.

The main things that were a bit off with your attempt were:

- Not escaping the / character with a backslash
- ^ indicates the start of the string to match but you had it before "batches" instead of "\ /batches"
- Good to test the regex here: https://regex101.com/